# Highlight entire line according to pattern match

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm trying to get to vim or nvim to highlight the entire gui line if there is a match on the screen.

I have no idea how to begin approaching this or what to search for.

[image]

I'm able to get vim to highlght according to a pattern match, but I want it to highlight the entire gui width like it does at the bottom of the screen (in black) as shown above.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible to highlight the entire line except `sign` feature. The following example uses `@/` register value to find the last searched lines and will show the `Search` highlight on them.

```
function! s:ToggleHighlightSearchLines()
    if !exists('s:id')
        let s:id = localtime()
        let lc = [line('.'), col('.')]
        call cursor([1, 1])
        let s:sc = &signcolumn
        let &signcolumn = 'no'
        sign define hlsLines linehl=Search
        let s:sp = 0
        while 1
            let ln = search(@/, 'W')
            if ln == 0 | break | endif
            execute 'sign place ' . s:id . ' line=' . ln . ' name=hlsLines'
            let s:sp += 1
        endwhile
        call cursor(lc)
    else
        while 0 < s:sp
            execute 'sign unplace ' . s:id
            let s:sp -= 1
        endwhile
        sign undefine hlsLines
        let &signcolumn = s:sc
        unlet s:id s:sp s:sc
    endif
endfunction
command! ToggleHLSLines call s:ToggleHighlightSearchLines()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot the response. Would it be possible to explain your solution in a little more detail? I'm really inexperienced using `vimscript`